# how to set flow variables inside expression component in mule

Tags: mule

```
<set-variable variableName="tempId" value="8000" doc:name="Variable" />
<expression-component doc:name="Expression">
<![CDATA[
temp1 =  message.payload.getRootElement().selectNodes('//palns/*');
foreach (plan1 : temp1){
plan1.selectSingleNode('planid').text = #[flowVars.tempId];
}       ]]></expression-component>
```

Above is my code . I can't set flow variable value inside expression component.
if i hardcode my value like below `plan1.selectSingleNode('planid').text = '4000';` 
It is working.

But I want my flow variables value . Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the expression wrapper #[] as its not needed in expression-component:

```
plan1.selectSingleNode('planid').text = flowVars.tempId;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<set-variable variableName="tempId" value="8000" doc:name="Variable" />
<expression-component doc:name="Expression">
<![CDATA[
temp1 =  message.payload.getRootElement().selectNodes('//palns/*');
foreach (plan1 : temp1){
plan1.selectSingleNode('planid').text = flowVars.tempId;
}       ]]></expression-component>
```

Expression component doesn't take #[]